# How to parse JSON nested string into C#

Tags: c#, json

I have string of this kind

```
string JsonDemo = @"{'status':'OK','articles':[{'key1':'value'},'Maqbool']}";
```

I want to get values of status, articles, Key1 in seprate varriables in C# window Form application.

I know [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) can be helpful for me but I am not getting what can be the exact code for doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be using the `JObject` class. You could deserialize it to a custom class too. `articles` is an array, that's why I'm retrieving the first element `{'key1':'value'}` with index `0`.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(JsonDemo);
string status = obj["status"].Value<string>();
string key = obj["articles"][0]["key1"].Value<string>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man a simple Jobject and all problems solved...thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) or visual studio itself has paste special option to generate the class against the json being provided:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<object> articles { get; set; }
}
```

and then we can deserialize it using NewtonSoft.Json library :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JsonDemo);
```